# How do i clear input,select and textarea fields after cloning

Tags: javascript, ajax, clone

i'm create form for expose item  i want fresh text field. when user click button ADD

```js
function fncAdd() { //ADD ROW AND CLONE
  var tb = document.getElementById('tbl');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody'); // fixed IE :>
  tb.insertBefore(tbody, null);
  var clone = document.getElementById('cln').cloneNode(true);
  tbody.insertBefore(clone, null);
}

function fncDelete() { //DELETE ROW
  var tb = document.getElementById('tbl');
  var del = tb.rows.length;
  if (del > 1) {
    tb.deleteRow(del - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<tr id="cln"> //CALL CLONE FUNCTION
  <div align="center">1</div>
  </td>
  <?php  //CONNECT DATABASE
          include 'dbConfig.php';
          $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accountcode ORDER BY acc_id ASC ");
          $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
          ?>
  <td>
    <select id="accountcode"> //DROPDOWN 2ND BY AJAX
      <option value=""> - - Please select - - </option>
      <?php
             if($rowCount > 0){
                 while($row=$query->fetch_assoc()){
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['acc_id'].'">'.$row['acc_name'].'</option>';
                 }
              }else{
                 echo '<option value="">Accountcode not available</option>';
              }
             ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="item"> //DROPDOWN 2ND BY AJAX
      <option value=""> - - Select accountcode first - -</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td> //DETAIL BOX
    <textarea rows=4 cols=25 class="txtDETAIL" maxlength="100"> </textarea>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="txtAMOUNT" size="5"> //AMOUNT BOX
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="txtUNIT" size="5"> //UNIT BOX
  </td>
  <td> //NOTE BOX
    <textarea rows=4 cols=15 class="note" maxlength="60">  </textarea>
  </td>
  <td> //UPLOADFILE FOR PICTURE OR STOCK
    <a href='upload.php?id={$row[' id="id" ']}'>CLICK</a>
  </td>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="fncAdd()"> //BUTTON ADD
    <input type="button" value="DELETE" onClick="fncDelete()"> //BUTTON DELETE
  </p>
```

I am having trouble to create text field value when user click button i want to clone function not copy old value from 1st row and column NO can auto increment

how can i do that

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpuZ5.png)

Answer (score 1):

To clear form data you can use,

```
document.getElementById("form1").reset();
```

Your form should look like,

```
<form id="form1">
   <input .....
</form>
```

Comment: @StrikerBlade where did you put `document.getElementById("form1").reset();`

Comment: between tb.insertBefore(tbody, null);  and  var clone = document.getElementById('cln').cloneNode(true);                                                        i do this right ?

Comment: Ok, then you need to add form tag `<form id="formid">`

Comment: yeah its reset but column ORDER not follow up and i want to column NO increase 1 by 1 when click ADD

Comment: That means, you need to update the value in a text field. To do that you can use `document.getElementById('inputid').value = newvalue;`. In this case you might not need to reset the values, just change it

Comment: yeah that right i not need to reset values i need to keep old values from first row and the next row . by clone copy form not values

Answer (score 0):

Something to be aware of, is the cloned element has unique ID's (eg, append -1 etc onto the original ID).

Also, I've recently done this using jQuery, however, I used string.replace(regex, ''); instead of this method.

Oh yeah, an example to edit to suit your situation:

```
var element = document.getElementById('id-of-element').cloneNode(true);

element.childNodes[x].nextSibling.childNodes[y].value = '';

document.getElementById('target-element').insertBefore(element, null);
```

Kind regards,

Comment: thx. man i try to change  but i use class replace id ajax its not working i don't know why

Comment: Have just updated my post, hope it helps.
Yeah, you should be able to access it via the nodes, then set the value that way.

Comment: Pls tell me x and y its mean ?  thank you for helping

Comment: Let's say, when you have multiple <p> tag's inside a <div> tag, the <p> tags will then be accessible in an array like style using childNodes keyword.

In this case, x and y are both ints, representing which childNode you would like to access, traversing down the tree, until you reach the input box you're wanting to set the value of, to null.

You can think of it as a line of cars, and counting from left to right, you select which car you want to change the colour of. So, x increment will represent each car.

If the cars trail around the corner, then you can say that those cars are y.

Comment: thank you so much Gatty. Can you recommend if i want to increase row when i click button . Case in my table have 2dropdown by ajax with SQL and 4 text .suppose I don't choose to use clone function ?